# Preventing re-rendering when trying to pass data/state between React siblings

Tags: reactjs, state

My components keep re-rendering as I try to update state from one child component to its sibling. This routes through the parent component so I assume that is why it rerenders the whole page. I only need Child Component 2 to re-render when the data is updated in Child Component 3. What is happening in this case is it is all re-rendering and then some drawers are closing creating bad UX. I have tried to use React.context to get around this but no luck at the moment. I'd appreciate advice (here is a minimal reproduction)

```
//React Context Creator:

import React from "react";

interface RangeHighlightsContextProps {
  setRangeHighlights: (highlights: number[]) => void;
  rangeHighlights: number[];
}

export const RangeHighlightsContext = React.createContext<RangeHighlightsContextProps>({
  setRangeHighlights: () => {},
  rangeHighlights: [],
});


// Parent component:
import { RangeHighlightsContext } from "./contexts/RangeHighlightContext";

const [rangeHighlights, setRangeHighlights] = useState<number[]>([]);

[...]

<RangeHighlightsContext.Provider value={{ setRangeHighlights, rangeHighlights }}>
  <ChildComponent1 />
  <ChildComponent2 />
</RangeHighlightsContext.Provider>

// Child Component 1:

function ChildComponent1(){
const { setRangeHighlights } = useContext(RangeHighlightsContext);

function handleRangeHighlightsChange(highlights: number[]) {
  setRangeHighlights(highlights);
}

  return(
  <div  onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          handleRangeHighlightsChange([1,2,3]);
        }}>Click Here</div>
  )
}

// Child Component 2:

function childComponent2(){
  const newHighlights = useContext(RangeHighlightsContext);

  return(
    <div>{newHighlights.rangeHighlights}</div>
  )
}
```

Here is how the drawers's state is set in the child component:

```
  const [drawerState, setDrawerState] = useState("none");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!drawerOpen) {
      setDrawerState("none");
    }
    if (drawerOpen) {
      console.log("opening");
      setDrawerState("block");
    }
  }, [drawerOpen]);

  function handleDrawer() {
    setDrawerOpen((drawerOpen) => !drawerOpen);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
return (
  <div onClick={handleRangeHighlightsChange([1,2,3])}>Click Here</div>
)
```

You're calling `handleRangeHighlightsChange` here, instead of passing it as a function.

To pass as a function means (simply put) to only write the name of the function

```js
onClick={handleRangeHighlightsChange}
```

but since you have arguments that need to be provided by you `[1, 2, 3]`, you would want to wrap this function call `handleRangeHighlightsChange([1, 2, 3])` with an anonymous arrow function, the result ends up being:

```js
return (
  <div onClick={() => handleRangeHighlightsChange([1, 2, 3])}>Click Here</div>
)
```

Notice the `() => ...` here.
But how does this not 'call' a function? it may look like it does (to a beginner). Well, to call this anonymous function, you would awkwardly need to write it like this:

```js
(() => handleRangeHighlightsChange([1, 2, 3]))()
```

But we do not want to do that in our case, obviously. I only put it as reference.

Comment: Very sorry - when i wrote the minimal example i missed that - I have updated it - but I already had an anonymous function in there as you can now see. Thank you for pointing it out, any other advice?

Comment: Re-rendering does not reset state values (flipping booleans -> closing drawers), it's quite the opposite. Not enough information here, from what I can tell, perhaps I'm missing something

Comment: But when the parent component re-renders the drawers state? added some further info to op.